# DataAnotation to validate a model, how do I validate it so that the date is not in the future?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have the Review Model, I am trying to validate the model, so that
when the user selects a date, it can't be the date in the future.

Review.cs

```
public class Review : BaseEntity{

    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You need a restaurant name!")]
    public string RestaurantName {get; set;}

    [What do I put in here??]
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}


}
```

I am a newbie, and the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation) is kind of hard to understand.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: Please link to the documentation you are having trouble understanding.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation I don't know how to compare the datetime

Comment: If you also want client side validation, the  use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[LessThan]` or similar attribute or implement your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: Great article, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a custom validation attribute which does your custom logic and use that to decorate your property name.

```
public class DateLessThanOrEqualToToday : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return "Date value should not be a future date";
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object objValue,
                                                   ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dateValue = objValue as DateTime? ?? new DateTime();

        //alter this as needed. I am doing the date comparison if the value is not null

        if (dateValue.Date > DateTime.Now.Date)
        {
           return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Now in your view model, decorate your property name with this new custom attribute

```
[DateLessThanOrEqualToToday]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

This custom validation attribute is primarly focusing on your specific validation logic. You can alter it to include more null checks, minimum value check etc as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Do I make this class in the Review.cs file??

Comment: I would create a separate class and keep it under a folder like "CustomValidations" or so for better readability

Answer (score 4):

Try **custom validation** or **standard model validation** with attributes.

First option, set attribute on property **standard dataannotations validation**:

- Set **DateType** attribute with errormessage properties and dateformatstring.
- Set **Range** attribute if you want.
- Set **Display** attribute for show label on screen.

  ```
  [DataType(DataType.Date), ErrorMessage = "Please enter a correct date format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm", DisplayFormat( DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true )]
  [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2016", "1/1/2011")]
  [Display(Name = "My Date")]
  public DateTime Date {get; set;}
  ```

Second option, **Custom validation method**:

You must extend the **ValidationAttribute** class and override `IsValid`:

```
public class MyDateValidation: ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // check your business date property  
        DateTime myDatetime;
        bool isParsed = DateTime.TryParse((string)value, out myDatetime);
        if(!isParsed)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

[MyDateValidation(ErrorMessage="Your message")]
public Datetime myDate { get; set; }
```

See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608083/custom-dataannotation-isvalid-not-called/39608988#39608988) about this subject.

Comment: `[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/2016", "1/1/2011")]` What is the format of "1/1/2016" and "1/1/2011"? MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom validator for this. You can name it as you wish, for example.

```
[DateNotInTheFuture]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Process itself is explained in good detail in this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx

Summarised:

- Create new sealed public class that inherits ValidationAttribute
- Inside that class implement an override for IsValid method.
- Write your custom validation logic inside IsValid method and return the result