# Razor/MVC Empty List Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, zero

I have a SelectList of IDs that the user can choose zero-many items into a `List`. By default the validation logic appears to require at least one element to be selected. I have tried using the annotation `[MinLength(0)]` as various documentation implies that it applies to not only strings but collections/lists.

The obvious answer to my question is to just disable validation of the property.

The slightly less obvious answer is to write my own custom `ValidationAttribute` which seems to be more effort than warranted.

I am looking if  there is another simple way.

My ViewModel property:

```
        public List<int> DiverIDList { get; } = new List<int>();
```

My CSHTML:

```
@{
    var DiverSL = (SelectList)ViewData["DiverSL"];
}
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="DiverIDList" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="DiverIDList" class="form-control"
            asp-items="@DiverSL" size="8">
        <option value="">-- Select Divers --</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="DiverIDList" class="text-danger" />
</div>
```

Comment: This question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39608083/custom-dataannotation-isvalid-not-called When creating a custom validationattribute an empty list will also not be called. However if you build your custom validationattribute to inherit from requiredattribute it wlll always get called, even if empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to better understand the problem, I decided to create a custom `ValidationAttribute` derived from `RequiredAttribute`. Although I was able to verify that my new validation attribute's `IsValid` was getting called, there were still cases when the `ICollection.Count == 0` was causing the custom validation to not be called and the server `ModelState` contained an error. Something in the framework is bypassing attribute based validation in this case.

Because I have Nullable enabled, I tried the different combinations of making the `List` nullable or not. No change in behavior.

The only viable solution appears to be disabling validation for that property. This requires two steps:

1. In the OnPost method before calling `ModelState.IsValid`, insert a call to `ModelState.Remove("ModelDiver.DiverIDList");`
2. In the CSHTML, add `data-val="false"` to the `<select>` tag.